# How to disable buttons when drag & drop div row has moved in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not to sure how to attack the following scenario.

I have a `form` with a row which is drag and drop-able and this is working perfectly.  The issue I have is that I want to disable some buttons when the rows do not match `page load` and re-enable when they do.

I have the below jQuery code so far:

```
var $form = $('form'),
origForm = $form.serialize();

// Drag & drop for existing rules
    $(function () {
        $("#sortableRows").sortable();
        $("#sortableRows").disableSelection();
    });

    // Check to see if form defaults have changed
$('form :input').change(function () {
    if ($form.serialize() !== origForm) {
        addDisable();
    } else {
        removeDisable();
    }
});

// Added the disabled attribute when form changes
var addDisable = function () {
    $("button[name='addButton'], button[name='modifyButton'], button[name='deleteButton'], button[name='activeButton'], button[name='inactiveButton'], input[name='searchDialPlanBox']").attr('disabled', true);
}

// Removes the disabled attribute
var removeDisable = function () {
    $("button[name='addButton'], button[name='modifyButton'], button[name='deleteButton'], button[name='activeButton'], button[name='inactiveButton'], input[name='searchDialPlanBox']").removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

As I said the drag and drop and the disable/enable functions are working fine of everything else e.g. I `disable` the listed buttons when an `input` is changed but no sure on on how to do this when the `div` `row` is moved.

Got part of it working but stuck on when moving other divs as the first on works fine but other always fall into the `Else`

[Drag & Drop Does Not Disable Buttons As Doesn't Fall Into Correct IF Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54672869/drag-drop-does-not-disable-buttons-as-doesnt-fall-into-correct-if-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also give `callback function` like below for `sortable`

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
    change: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Comment: Please see my other post and see if you can help as i have it working for my first div but all other ones it falls into my 'Else' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54672869/drag-drop-does-not-disable-buttons-as-doesnt-fall-into-correct-if-statement

Answer (score 0):

Where is the code responsible for drag and drop handling?
For now Ill assume that is done by `.sortable()`. Then you would have to look into the docs of this function and search for events which are triggered on drag/drop and attach an listener which then calls disable/enable button.

Something like:

```
/*...*/.sortable({
  dragStart: addDisable,
  dragEnd: removeDisable
})
```

If you want to enable/disable depending on certain conditions then of course you have to implement that in the event handler too.