# Drag & drop does not disable buttons as it doesn't fall into correct `if` statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not to sure how to attack the following scenario.

I have a `form` with a row which is drag and drop-able and this is working perfect.  The issue I have is that I want to disable some buttons when the rows do not match `page load` and re-enable when they do. I can get it to do it if I move the second row but not the third above the second

I have the below jQuery code so far:

```
var $form = $('form'),
    origForm = $form.serialize();

$('#sortableRows').sortable({
    start: function (event, ui) {
        var start_pos = ui.item.index();
        ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
        var start_pos = ui.item.data('start_pos');
        var index = ui.placeholder.index();

        if (start_pos < index) {
            addDisable();
        } else {
            removeDisable();
        }
    }
});

// Check to see if form defaults have changed
$('form :input').change(function () {
    if ($form.serialize() !== origForm) {
        addDisable();
    } else {
        removeDisable();
    }
});

// Added the disabled attribute when form changes
var addDisable = function () {
    $("button[name='addButton'], button[name='modifyButton'], button[name='deleteButton'], button[name='activeButton'], button[name='inactiveButton'], input[name='searchDialPlanBox']").attr('disabled', true);
}

// Removes the disabled attribute
var removeDisable = function () {
    $("button[name='addButton'], button[name='modifyButton'], button[name='deleteButton'], button[name='activeButton'], button[name='inactiveButton'], input[name='searchDialPlanBox']").removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

As I said this works fine if I move the first row below the next row but does not work for if I move my third row above the second.

I know it has something to do with my `IF` `if (start_pos < index)` as the `index` for my other rows is higher the `start_pos` but I can't figure out the correct thing to use at all.

I also tried using the `update` on the function but I couldn't get this to work.

**HTML (Dummy data, ID's, names etc)**

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<!-- Existing rules header row-->
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h4>Existing dial plans</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Table header row -->
    <!-- Row below is NOT sortable -->
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="toDrExistingTableHeader col-xs-1 col-md-1">
                Order
            </div>
            <div class="toDrExistingTableHeader col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                Start time
            </div>
            <div class="toDrExistingTableHeader col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                End time
            </div>
            <div class="toDrExistingTableHeader col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                Days of week
            </div>
            <div class="toDrExistingTableHeader col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                Days of month
            </div>
            <div class="toDrExistingTableHeader col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                Month(s)
            </div>
            <div class="toDrExistingTableHeader col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                Go to
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Table details rows -->
<!-- Row below is NOT sortable -->
<div class="form-group toDrDialPlanTableRowDivider">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
                <span id="orderNumber" name="orderNumber" class="radio">
                    1
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                <span id="startTime" name="startTime" class="radio">
                    08:00
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                <span id="endTime" name="endTime" class="radio">
                    17:00
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                <span id="weekDays" name="weekDays" class="radio">
                    Mon - Fri
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                <span id="monthDays" name="monthDays" class="radio">
                    01 - 20
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                <span id="months" name="months" class="radio">
                    Jan - Dec
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                <span id="goTo" name="goTo" class="radio">
                    Working hours
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Rows in the below 'DIV' ARE sortable -->
<div id="sortableRows">
    <div class="form-group toDrDialPlanTableRowDivider sortableRows">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
                    <span id="orderNumber1" class="radio">
                        2
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                    <span id="startTime1" name="startTime" class="radio">
                        08:00
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                    <span id="endTime1" name="endTime" class="radio">
                        17:00
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                    <span id="weekDays1" name="weekDays" class="radio">
                        Mon - Fri
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                    <span id="monthDays1" name="monthDays" class="radio">
                        01 - 20
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                    <span id="months1" name="months" class="radio">
                        Jan - Dec
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1" style="padding-right: 0px">
                    <span id="goTo1" name="goTo" class="radio">
                        Working hours
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1" tyle="padding: 0;">
                    <div id="radioButton1" name="radioButton" class="radio c-radio">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrows-v" style="font-size: large"></i>
                        </div>
                        <label class="col-xs-6">
                            <input type="radio" name="actionRadioButton" value="option1">
                            <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group toDrDialPlanTableRowDivider sortableRows">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
                    <span id="orderNumber2" class="radio">
                        3
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                    <span id="startTime2" name="startTime" class="radio">
                        17:01
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                    <span id="endTime2" name="endTime"  class="radio">
                        07:59
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                    <span id="weekDays2" name="weekDays" class="radio">
                        Mon - Sun
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                    <span id="monthDays2" name="monthDays" class="radio">
                        All
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                    <span id="months2" name="months" class="radio">
                        Jan - Dec
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1" style="padding-right: 0px">
                    <span id="goTo2" name="goTo" class="radio">
                        Out of office hours
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1"
                    style="padding: 0;">
                    <div id="radioButton2" name="radioButton" class="radio c-radio">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrows-v" style="font-size: large"></i>
                        </div>
                        <label class="col-xs-6">
                            <input type="radio" name="actionRadioButton" value="option1">
                            <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a snippet/jsfiddle?

Comment: could you please provide html code as well ?

Comment: @VasuKuncham HTML added for you